# JQuery function not working - sometimes

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, relative-path

I have 2 identical code blocks, when it is loaded at first from the index in controller it works, but when I submit a form and load this code, my autocomplete isn't working for a field.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>public/blue.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />    
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>public/jquery-1.6.1.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            alert('workin');


            //$(".publish-bottom").hide();
            $(".publish-right").hide();



            //title field
            $.ajax({

                type: "GET",
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                url: "publishlinks/search_movies",
                success:
                    function(response) {

                        alert('response received');
                        alert(response);

                        $("#title").autocomplete({
                            source: response,
                            minLength: 2,
                            select: function (event, ui) {

                                var selectedObj = ui.item;
                                var imgFilename = ui.item;                              
                                imgFilename = imgFilename.value;
                                imgFilename = imgFilename.replace(/ /g,"_");

                                $(".selected-right").empty();
                                $(".selected-left").empty();
                                $(".publish-right").show();

                                //render selected media
                                $(".selected-left").append('<a href="<?php echo "#"; ?>"> <img class="movie-img" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>img_test/' + imgFilename + '"></a>');
                                $(".selected-right").append('<h4>' + selectedObj.title + '</h4>');
                                $(".selected-right").append(selectedObj.plot);

                                //update publication id  
                                $("#movieId").attr("value", selectedObj.movieid);
                                $("#selected-item").attr("value", "selected");

                                $(".new-movie").show();

                                //get selected item's publications
                                getPublications(selectedObj);

                            }

                        }).data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {

                            var imgFilename = item.label;
                            imgFilename = imgFilename.replace(/ /g,"_");

                            return $( "<li></li>" )
                                .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                                .append( '<a>' + '<img src="http://localhost/portal/img_test/' + imgFilename + '" width="40" height="63" />' + item.title + '</a>' )
                                .appendTo(ul);
                        }

                    }

             });

        });

</script>

function search_movies() {

    $movies = $this->movie_model->get_movies();     
    echo json_encode($movies);

}

//works fine    
function index() {

            $this->load->model('user_model');
            $data['user'] = $this->user_model->get_user($this->session->userdata('userid'));

            $data['loggedIn'] = $this->is_logged_in() ? true : false;
            $this->load->view('header_view', $data);
            $this->load->view('publish_links_view');

}
```

**Code for form submit:**

```
            //Not working for autocomplete
            $error['linksError'] = 'You must select an item to publish links for.';         

            $data['user'] = $this->user_model->get_user($this->session->userdata('userid'));
            $data['loggedIn'] = $this->is_logged_in() ? true : false;
            $this->load->view('header_view', $data);
            $this->load->view('publish_links_view', $error);
```

Comment: that code tells us nothing, please post the actual function you are referring to

Comment: What is `response` going to be? Unless it's a URI/URL, it most likely won't work.

Comment: @Nathan Hoad Why not? It's a json formatted string.

Comment: "Autocomplete can be customized to work with various data sources, by just specifying the source option. A data source can be: an Array with local data, a String, specifying a URL,
a Callback" http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete

Answer (score 2):

I agree with user555116, we don't have enough information.  But I do see one problem with your code.  This may be the issue, may not.  You have your functions defined in this block, you say:

```
$(function() {

});
```

Well that, is the short form of this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


});
```

For both blocks, all jquery does is save the code in these blocks.  When jquery recieves the DOM loaded event, it runs each function, in the order that you sent it to jquery.  Also, each of these functions do not implicitly have access to the other. Unless you create a reference to the function defined inside the doc ready blocks in some way, they will disappear after the block executes. However, in this case, the easier (and more correct) solution is to simply remove function definitions that from the `$(function() { })`.

Comment: I've discovered publishlinks/search_movies isn't getting a successful response from the controller.

Comment: Then it sounds like it might be a php error.  I notice that you don't have a `data` option in your ajax statement.  Doesn't the `publishlinks/search_movies` need any variables?  Also, you have your ajax in a jquery doc ready block, which itself is in a doc ready block.  Although this code will still run, it serves no purpose.  You can save a few bytes by moving the `$.ajax()` out the `$()` block.

Comment: exactly, when you pass a function to the global JQuery object it defaults to `$(document).ready()` +1

Comment: Of course I mean the `$(function() {})` block

Comment: search_movies() simply echoes a json encoded string.

Comment: Ok.. but then I can't see the problem.  Would you mind posting the link to your page?  I'll take a quick look.  I'm betting your getting downvoted as it seems your problem isn't in the code your supplying. Although that does seem a bit much.  The natives are restless today.

Comment: But again, there's nothing syntactically wrong with that code either.  In your case, without the live example, we can't look around and see what's going on.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a live version, in b4 MORE LIKE FORTUNARELY.

Comment: I'm getting a response status 200 for search_movies, just no response in the ajax code. Weird, I'm getting the html document as the response in the response packet!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4107/discussion-between-150poundsofdonamite-and-amiawizard)